# Reactjs: Axios.post call returns array object from database - need to map to other component

Tags: reactjs, rest, asynchronous, redux, axios

I've been struggling with this for a couple days, and any help would be appreciated.

In this component, I have tried to do an HTTP call to my server and database. After parsing the response, using JSON.parse, I am getting back a correctly formed JSON object. I then want to map through that object and for each return a new component (called HistoryItem).

The code below attempts to do this by placing the object into the component state, but it is causing an infinite refresh loop. Previously I had tried a functional component.

The original iteration of this component did work. But it pulled a static JSON object from my client side files. Therefore, I am confident code works without the http call.

It seems to me I am doing something wrong with the async, which is disallowing the JSON object received asynchronously from being rendered.

Below is the main component. Note the component imports the username from redux. This feeds the HTTP call, so that it retrieves only records associated with the logged in user. Again, everything looks fine on the server/database end...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import style from './history.css';
import HistoryItem from './HistoryItem/historyItem';
import data from '../../config/fakermyhistory.json';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';


class History extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
       compiledList:[]
     }
   }

   getData(){
   this.state.compiledList.map((call, i) => {
     const shaded = (call.rated) ? 'lightgrey' :  'white';
     console.log("shaded", shaded);
       return(
       <Link to={`/reviewpage/${call._id}`} key={call._id}
       style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color:'lightgrey'}}>
       <div style={{backgroundColor:shaded}}>
         <hr/>
         <HistoryItem call={call}/>
       </div>
     </Link>
   )
   })
 }


render(){
      axios.post('/api/history', {username: this.props.username})
      .then((res) => {
       const array = JSON.parse(res.request.response);
       this.setState({compiledList: array})
       console.log("res", array);}
     ).catch((err) => console.log("err", err));





return (
<div className={style.container}>
  <div className={style.historyHeader}>
    <div className={style.historyHeaderText}>
    Your Call History
  </div>
  </div>

  <div className={style.historyList}>
  {this.getData()};
  </div>
</div>
)
}
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      username:state.auth.username
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(History);
```

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Here is another version using it as a functional component. Also doesn't render (although no errors on this one)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import style from './history.css';
import HistoryItem from './HistoryItem/historyItem';
import data from '../../config/fakermyhistory.json';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';


const History =(props)=> {

   const getData=(props)=>{
     console.log("props", props);
     axios.post('/api/history', {username: props.username})
     .then((res) => {
      const array = JSON.parse(res.request.response);
      console.log("array", array);
      array.map((call, i) => {
        const shaded = (call.rated) ? 'lightgrey' :  'white';
        console.log("shaded", shaded);
          return(
          <Link to={`/reviewpage/${call._id}`} key={call._id}
          style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color:'lightgrey'}}>
          <div style={{backgroundColor:shaded}}>
            <hr/>
            <HistoryItem call={call}/>
          </div>
        </Link>
      )

      })

    }
    ).catch((err) => console.log("err", err));
 }

return (
<div className={style.container}>
  <div className={style.historyHeader}>
    <div className={style.historyHeaderText}>
    Your Call History
  </div>
  </div>

  <div className={style.historyList}>
  {getData(props)};
  </div>
</div>
)
}



const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      username:state.auth.username
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(History);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling axios in render function, try to invoke it from componentDidMount.
This will help you prevent the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks Piyush.

It still isn't rendering. For some reason I don't see the historyItem, even though the console.log (array), shows that the proper json object is feeding into the map function. 

That did prevent the infinite refresh though.

Comment: this is the reason why you have infinite rendering, each render calls another state update and that calls another render, which calls another axios and so on... if this is not an issue any more correctly described please accept Piyush answer and ask another question at StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks Alex - The infinite rendering was only one manifestation of the main problem which is that the historyItem components are not being rendered despite receiving a properly formatted json object. Why not? For some reason the return call is not returning the historyitem components to the page. Happy to pay you the bounty if you solve it.

Comment: @SteveRose in your getData() method, try to add this check this.state.compiledList.length > 0 && this.state.compiledList.map()

Comment: Thanks Piyush. No change. Do you see the console.log, under the map function. It is faithfully reporting that the data is reaching it as expected. Everything looks fine, until I try to pass each "call" object to the HistoryItem component. It's like the data just dies there, and the Link which wraps the HistoryItem component is simply not generated. I have no idea why not. 

I thought the problem might be HistoryItem, but when I plug in the static JSON data from my client side files, it works.

Comment: I figured it out! 

As I suspected, dumb error. I needed to add a simple "return" statement directly before the "array.map" call.

Thanks!

Comment: @SteveRose, if my answer solves your issue please accept the answer

Comment: @PiyushZalani, it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

To return the components rendered within the map function, it was necessary to add a "return" command before the map function was called:

```
return array.map((call, i) => {...
```